# Unix script - first letters of a string

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

When i run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
test="abcdr"
test2=${test:0:2}
echo $test2
```

I get the error: `script: 3: script: Bad substitution`

But then I type exactly the same commands in the terminal it works fine without any error

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you running your script? Is `bash` in `/bin/bash`? (check with `which bash`).

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @user3597432 Make it executable (`chmod u+x script`) and run it like `./script` or run it like `bash script`. `sh` **does not** support substrings.

Comment: That's the problem, when doing `sh script` you are making `sh` to interpret it, and shell does not accept this substitution. Instead, execute with `./script`, that will get `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your script with `sh`, which is not the same as `bash`. It doesn't support this type of substitution.
Run your script with

```
bash script
```

or make sure it's executable (`chmod u+x /path/to/script`) and run it directly

```
/path/to/script
```

If your current directory happens to be `/path/to`, you can just type

```
./script
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3597432 i don't see any issue in that script content, mostly the issue might be with bash version or how the script being executed. if you couldn't resolve by bash terminal, you can try korn shell if possible which is more convenient. just refer the ksh bin and script file to .ksh. ksh provides debug option execute with ksh -x script.ksh.